# Converting u"string" to "string" in Python without changing encoding

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following:

```
u'\x96'
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
'\x96'
```

Is there any way to do this? `str()` doesn't work, and when using `.encode(...)` it changes the encoding. My main goal is to be able to get the following result, so any shortcut to get there would also be accepted:

```
>>> '\x96'.decode("cp1252")
u'\u2013'
```

In other words, I have `u'\x96'` and I want `u'\u2013'`. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe you could decode to ascii rather than a specific ANSI codepage.

Comment: @David: But then you can't use anything above `\x7f`.

Comment: @Ignacio There won't be anything above `\x7f`!

Comment: @David: Did you see the `\x96` in the question?

Comment: @Ignacio I mean after the string has been unicode escaped as per mouad's answer.

Comment: If it is ASCII then by definition it is a 7-bit encoding which cannot represent characters with a higher code point than 0x7f.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
u'\x96'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode("cp1252")
```

Comment: This is a bit of a roundabout way. It would have a side-effect of turning any non-ISO-8859-1 character into a `\u` escape. For example, `u'\u00FF\u0100'` becomes `u'\xff\\u0100'`. Maybe you want that; I'd prefer the UnicodeEncodeError, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Latin-1 is the encoding that directly maps the first 256 characters of Unicode to their byte values.

```
>>> u'\x96'.encode('latin-1').decode("cp1252")
u'\u2013'
```

Comment: This would be the usual idiom. `latin-1` is an alias for ISO-8859-1.